# Kendo UI Grid - group by single field

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to use Kendo UI Grid to replace an existing grid in a page, without changing the backing business logic. I am able to query data grouped on a single field (the business and data layers are legacy code and not open for change).

In the Kendo UI grid, is it possible to allow grouping on any ONE field, but disallow adding more grouping fields?

Comment: to clarify... you want to allow a user to group the grip by any one column on the grid, and then once they have specified the group, don't allow any additional columns to be grouped? then, when they ungroup the current one, they can select a new column to group by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

#### Fields/Columns Setup

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Action).Groupable(false);
```

#### Grouping Configuration

```
.DataSource(ds => ds
    .Server()
    .Group(g => g.Add(p => p.ChangeDateTime)
)
```